# Random Freezes in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, ssd, ext4

It's my first time that I've been facing problems with Ubuntu on my machine, recently I've changed the SSD of my PC with a brand new one, it's working really well in Windows and the firmware is up to date.

**Hardware**

- Kingston A200 NVME 500Gb (BTRS and XFS)
- Hybrid Graphics(Intel HD 530, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M)

**Software**

- Nvidia Driver 440 (From the Official Repositories, Prime Profile: On Demand)
- Cuda Driver (From the official repository)
- Linux Kernel 5.4.0-42-generic (Secure boot enabled)

Sometimes, I'm using my laptop and Kwin stop working, I can't open the Application Launcher but I can change the window via the Alt + Tab key but after few seconds, the screen is completly frozen, I can't control the mouse, the temperature starts to increase, I can't switch to another console to check the error(Control + Alt + F2) and I can only restart my PC with the Magic SysRq key + REISUB.

Relevant info of my system:

Bios Version

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
E5CN63WW
```

RAM and SWAP Data:

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       3,9Gi       7,0Gi       1,3Gi       4,5Gi        10Gi
Swap:         3,8Gi       1,8Gi       2,0Gi
```

Swapiness

```
sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

The system journal `journalctl -k -b -1` (for me) didn't show anything relevant, but I'm attaching the messages with warning or alerts below, just in case I'm forgotting something

First log

```
aug 11 20:49:22 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: IRQ 125: no longer affine to CPU1
aug 11 20:49:22 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: IRQ 140: no longer affine to CPU4
aug 11 20:49:22 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: IRQ 124: no longer affine to CPU6
aug 11 20:49:22 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: IRQ 128: no longer affine to CPU6
aug 11 20:49:22 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: IRQ 138: no longer affine to CPU7
aug 11 20:49:22 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI: button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
aug 11 20:49:22 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
aug 11 20:49:23 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
aug 11 20:49:29 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 43 callbacks suppressed
aug 11 20:49:55 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: xfs filesystem being remounted at /run/systemd/unit-root/var/cache/private/fwupdmgr supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
```

Second log

```
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: [Firmware Bug]: TPM Final Events table missing or invalid
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: TAA CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html for more details.
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel:  #5 #6 #7
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_PR.CPU0._PPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_PR.CPU0._PCT], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_PR.CPU0._PSS], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_PR.CPU0.LPSS], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_PR.CPU0.TPSS], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_PR.CPU0.PSDF], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_PR.CPU0._PSD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_PR.CPU0.HPSD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_PR.CPU0.SPSD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: usb: port power management may be unreliable
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: xfs filesystem being remounted at / supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: asus_wmi: ASUS Management GUID not found
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Realtek Extended Controls Unit was not initialized!
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: thermal thermal_zone3: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  440.100  Fri May 29 08:45:51 UTC 2020
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
aug 11 21:02:01 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
aug 11 21:02:01 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20190816/nsarguments-59)
```

Third log

```
aug 11 21:44:10 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  440.100  Fri May 29 08:45:51 UTC 2020
aug 11 21:44:10 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: thermal thermal_zone3: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
aug 11 21:44:10 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
aug 11 21:44:13 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
aug 11 21:44:13 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20190816/nsarguments-59)
aug 11 22:21:25 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
aug 11 22:21:26 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
aug 11 22:22:31 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 37 callbacks suppressed
```

**Update**

I hard reinstalled Kubuntu 20.04.1 with EXT4 partition, it seems to be a SSD error, new information is below:

- nvme0n1p5 / partition
- nvme0n1p4 /home partition
  It occurs randomly when I'm using my PC and the computer is completly frozen.

```
[ 3378.408344] systemd-journald (423): Failed to write entry (22 items, 780 bytes), ignoring: Read-only 
[ 3378.408611] systemd-journald [423] : Failed to write entry (22 items, 769 bytes), ignoring: Read-only
```

Another log of the freezing error.

```
[ 827214225 EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p5): __ext4_find_entry:1531: inode #3407921: comm gmain: reading directory lblock 0
[ 827.214749] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p5): __ext4_find_entry:1531: inode #3407921: conn gmain: reading directory lblock 0 
[ 827.214764] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p5): __ext4_find_entry:1531: inode #3407921: comm gmain: reading directory lblock 0
```

Sometimes when I shutdown my laptop, this error occurs

```
[ 16918.166564] systemd-shutdown [1]: Remounting '/' timed out. issuing SIGKILL to PID 11240.
[ 16982.141788] nvme nvme0: Device not ready: aborting reset
[ 16982.143784] nvme : Removing after probe failure status: -19
```

**Update 2**

Using the Kubuntu Live ISO, I performed the fsck test, no issues found.

```
root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# fsck /dev/nvme0n1p3 
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 257827/6111232 files, 8741020/24413952 blocks
root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# echo $?
0
root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# fsck /dev/nvme0n1p5
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 754959/6447104 files, 10749435/25785856 blocks
root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# echo $?
0
```

Problem when restart

```
nvme nvme0: Device not ready; aborting reset
nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
Remounting '/' timed out, issuing SIGKILL to PID 7544.
```

The SMART analysis is the following:

```
sudo smartctl -i /dev/nvme0
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-42-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       KINGSTON SA2000M8500G
Serial Number:                      50026B7683BC98CE
Firmware Version:                   S5Z42105
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x2646
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x0026b7
Controller ID:                      1
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          500.107.862.016 [500 GB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            142.133.460.992 [142 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            0026b7 683bc98ce5
Local Time is:                      Wed Aug 26 23:49:45 2020 CEST


sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0         
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-42-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       KINGSTON SA2000M8500G
Serial Number:                      50026B7683BC98CE
Firmware Version:                   S5Z42105
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x2646
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x0026b7
Controller ID:                      1
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          500.107.862.016 [500 GB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            142.114.676.736 [142 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            0026b7 683bc98ce5
Local Time is:                      Wed Aug 26 23:51:50 2020 CEST
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     75 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     9.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.60W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.80W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0450W       -        -    3  3  3  3     2000    2000
 4 -   0.0040W       -        -    4  4  4  4    15000   15000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        30 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    3.966.522 [2,03 TB]
Data Units Written:                 6.036.943 [3,09 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 38.899.250
Host Write Commands:                46.064.389
Controller Busy Time:               601
Power Cycles:                       390
Power On Hours:                     241
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   160
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Thermal Temp. 1 Transition Count:   7
Thermal Temp. 1 Total Time:         24

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 256 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

[image: SSD Firmware]

Thanks for reading. What have I done wrong? Any comment is really appreciated!

Regards

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Dear @heynnema thanks for your answer, I've updated the requiered info. Regards.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Dear @heynnema I have tried all of your solutions, thank for them. Unfortunately I've been facing the same random freezes, I forgot to say that my System has Secure boot enabled (to Install the NVIDIA and CUDA Driver's). When my computer freezes, it didn't log the upcoming system and kernel events, but the last time, I got this message on my Screen
```acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
usb 1-2 device descriptor read/64 error 110```.

Comment: Did you disable TPM? Did you do all of the items in my answer? Edit your question and show me `lsusb`.

Comment: - [ X] MDS Mitigation, I've changed the grub file 
```(base) josejacomeb@josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK:~$ cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mds=full,nosmt"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```
- [X] NVME Firmware: Up  to date

Comment: - [X] NVME Firmware up to date: - [X] NVME Firmware: Up  to date

```
=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Percentage Used:                    0%
Controller Busy Time:               529
Power Cycles:                       340
Power On Hours:                     189
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   135
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
```

Comment: - [ ] Can't change TPM, no option in BIOS(Maybe behind Secure Boot)

- [X] Memory: No permanent problems

- [X] NVIDIA Driver: Up to date to the Ubuntu repository

Comment: @heynnema 
```lang-bash
 lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0670 Acer, Inc Lenovo EasyCamera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
 ```

Comment: Today's errors, I'd think it's a compatibility issue with Kingston's NVME Controller
```lang-bash
systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: (sd-sync), systemd-journal
INFO: task xfsaild/nvme0n1:437 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Tainted: P 5.4.0-42-generic 46-Ubuntu
```
```lang-bash
nvme nvme0: Device not ready: aborting reset 
nvme nvme0: Removing after probe failure status: -19 
Remounting '/' timed out, issuing SIGKILL to PID 9244.
```
```lang-bash
nvme nvme0: I/O 896 QID 4 timeout, aborting
nvme nvme0: I/O 897 QID 4 timeout, aborting
```

Comment: Thanks for the data... however... that kind of data belongs as an edit to your question... not in the comments... as it's almost impossible to read. Anyway, are you using XFS file system on your NVMe? You have SO MANY ERRORS, and they're all over the place, I'd recommend backing up your data, reinstalling Ubuntu, but with ext4 as the file system. I think the long term results would be better.

Comment: I'm so sorry @heynnema , I've reinstalled my OS with an EXT4 Partition and I can say it's a SSD error, does it have a solution? Maybe I'm planning to ask for refunding, or buying another SSD brand. Regards

Comment: Why do you say it's an SSD error?

Comment: @heynnema because my last SSD was a Samsung and I didn't have any problem, now ramdom hangs, the controller is not responding and the journalctl registry shows that the filesystem is in read-only mode, so I'm wondering if it's either a kernel problem or a hardware problem of my SSD

Comment: Did you check for new firmware for the SSD? Do you know how to run `fsck` on the drive? Look at the SMART Data?

Comment: @heynnema Kingston SSD Manager shows that I have the last firmware in my PC, I've attached the fsck analysis and the SMART data as well, thank you. regards.

Comment: Do you get any output from `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`?

Comment: @heynnema I didn't get any output of that command.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much @heynnema for your support, I've contacted Kingston Technical Support, If I have luck, I'll update this thread with the final solution. Regards

Comment: Thanks for keeping me updated!

Comment: Dear @heynnema , Kingston Engineers have answered me, the problem was about the Power Saving NVME Driver, please accept my answer. Thank you for your time. Regards

Comment: Thanks for the update! What a strange problem, huh? You wrote a good answer. I can't accept your answer though... you do that yourself... after you wait for two days. Then you can click the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was of a SSD features, the Autonomous Power State Transitions(APST) was causing the freezes. To mitigate it, until they will release the fix, include the line `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0` in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` options. For instance:

```bsh
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: This solution has also been effective for me, after having problems on my system, running Mint, that also has a Kingston NVMe. However, the breif comments leave open many questions. I have created [another issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612096) requesting further clarification on the solution, though I would be happy to see such elaboration provided here.

Answer (score 1):

**BIOS**

Your BIOS is current at version E5CN63WW.

**MDS**

You have MDS and TAA errors:

```
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: TAA CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html for more details.
```

**Mitigation control on the kernel command line**

The kernel command line allows to control the MDS mitigations at boot time with the option “mds=”. The valid arguments for this option are:

```
full
```

If the CPU is vulnerable, enable all available mitigations for the MDS vulnerability, CPU buffer clearing on exit to userspace and when entering a VM. Idle transitions are protected as well if SMT is enabled.

It does not automatically disable SMT.

```
full,nosmt
```

The same as mds=full, with SMT disabled on vulnerable CPUs. This is the complete mitigation.

```
off
```

Disables MDS mitigations completely.

---

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mds=full,nosmt"
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`.

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`

**Note: Understand that you'll take a HUGE performance hit on multi-cpu or multi-core configurations.**

**Note: If the performance hit is too great, try `mds=full` instead of `mds=full,nosmt`.**

**NVMe**

```
Kingston A200 NVME 500Gb
```

You may have a firmware problem:

```
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.
```

Go to the manufacturer's web site and check for newer firmware.

**TPM**

You have TPM errors:

```
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
aug 11 21:01:58 josejacomeb-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK kernel: acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
```

Check to make sure your `Software Updates` are current, and that you're running the latest kernel.

Check your BIOS for a TPM setting, and disable TPM if possible.

**memory**

Your swap and vm.swappiness settings look fine.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Nvidia**

You have Nvidia driver 440. There's a newer version available, 450.57, and it can be downloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/).

[image]

[image]